# How can a daemon stay active while using no memory?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, process, ram

I come up with this question while using the `ps aux` command.

[image: ps aux]

Here I can see that a few processes are at *0% CPU 0% MEM 0 VSZ 0 RSS*.

If a daemon is not using any memory, why and how could it be displayed in the first place ? I kind of understand that *0% CPU* usage mean the process is not currently in use but wouldn't *0% MEM* mean no process at all ?

I wanted to check if this was somehow systems daemon specific so I made a simple C program with an infinite loop, without any variables.

```
void main()
{
        while (1){}
}
```

This time VSZ and RSS have actual values, while MEM staying at 0%. 
[image: memory test]

What is happening here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%MEM` is probably not fully documented on your system. AIX manual about `ps` command says:

> `%MEM`
>
> > Calculated as the sum of the number of working segment and code
> >     segment pages in memory times 4 (that is, the RSS value), divided by
> >     the size of the real memory in use, in the machine in KB, times 100,
> >     rounded to the nearest full percentage point. This value attempts to
> >     convey the percentage of real memory being used by the process.
> >     Unfortunately, like RSS, it tends the exaggerate the cost of a process
> >     that is sharing program text with other processes. Further, the
> >     rounding to the nearest percentage point causes all of the processes
> >     in the system that have RSS values under 0.005 times real memory size
> >     to have a %MEM of 0.0.

As you could have suspected by examining the output, some rounding have been applied. So if the value is too low %0.0 is printed.

And, this measure percentage of the real memory usage, which means that it doesn't reflect the size of the process but only which part of the process is actually mapped to real memory.

In your first case %0.0 for CPU just means that the process exists but actually does nothing and it is probably in a waiting state (or consuming a very small percentage of the processing power), not "that it is is not currently in use". In your second case, your process is active, it is in fact very busy (this is what `%97.7` reflects), but what it does is stupid (infinite loop doing nothing).

To understand all of this, you may read about process state, process scheduling and virtual memory.

Answer (score 1):

While Jean-Baptiste's answer is correct as far as it goes, I believe it's more significant in this case that all of the 0 memory in all three fields processes you're noting are kernel threads.  Their memory is all kernel memory, and doesn't show up on top or ps.  You can tell it's a kernel thread on linux both by the command being encapsulated by brackets and by the process consuming no memory in the VSZ column.  (That's the column that represents basically everything that could be considered the process's memory.  It's only 0 for kernel threads, and that only because they don't properly report their memory.

Also note that with a start time in 2018 and having consumed no more than 1 minute 41 seconds, none of those jobs are really very active.